# Packing multiple OSGi bundles in the same jar

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I am very new to the OSGi platform.

Having an OSGi bundle `B1` that has a dependency to another bundle `B2`, which is very probably not provided by the container, can I package both bundles in the same `jar`?

If yes: howto do that? what would happen if the `jar` is installed and the bundle is already installed?

Comment: Just curious why you are trying to do this? You can just load both your B1 and B2 bundles.

Comment: @codesalsa because we cannot force someone (non-technical) to download two files. Actually there is a plugin framework over OSGi, and the most used way to install such a plugin is by providing a jar file (which is a bundle).

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do this... kind of.

Normally OSGi bundles are JAR files because they need to have a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. The OSGi framework cannot directly read your "multi-bundle" JAR.

However, installing bundles in OSGi involves calling the `BundleContext.installBundle` method. This method has two flavours, one of them takes an InputStream as a parameter; this InputStream should supply the content of the OSGi bundle. Therefore you can take your big JAR and read it with a JarInputStream, passing the individual entries to the `installBundle` method.

Comment: I have seen you have a nice book for FREE: "OSGi in Practice" on your site. Thank you very much, Neil!!!

Answer (score 1):

Although OSGi doesn't directly support multiple bundles in the same jar, there is a standard for multiple bundles in the same *archive*, which solves the distribution problem you're trying to address. Unfortunately, it may introduce an extra problem in your scenario, because it's part of enterprise OSGi, rather than core OSGi, so it wouldn't be part of a bare bones Equinox or Felix framework. If you have more control over the starting platform your users are using, it may do what you need.

The basic idea is that you package all your bundles into a zip with a .esa extension, along with a simple manifest. You can then distribute the esa file. This tutorial includes lots more detail: 
http://coderthoughts.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/osgi-subsystems.html?m=1