# OSGi thread-safety cautions

Tags: thread-safety, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have heard that using the low-level OSGi API generally can induce some thread-safety problems, like when registering a service implementation (e.g in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DBjgJpqanh0#t=2178)).

**Q1**. What kind of problems are those? Could someone show an example?

In particular I want to install a JPA bundle (probably EclipseLink) in an OSGi container (Apache Felix) from within my bundle, where the JPA bundle is jarred with my bundle (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148375/packing-multiple-osgi-bundles-in-the-same-jar) for details).

**Q2.** What kind of thread-safety bugs could I have if I simply call `BundleContext.installBundle()`? If there are any problems, could "Spring DM" help me solve those problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: OSGi bundles live in a concurrent world so any code that is callable by others will give rise to thread safety issues.
Q2: Install bundle causes events, these  events are delivered on other threads so if you subscribe to those events you must be careful when you share state.
Q3: No, Spring DM does not solve this problem for you.

Overall, OSGi actually minimizes concurrency issues if you use the service model with Declarative Services (DS). I find that the strict timing of DS ensures the important happens-before relations that avoids most concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2):

An OSGi runtime generally has many thread runnig within it. The OSGi framework itself may use threads to deliver events asynchronously. So code which runs in OSGi should generally be thread safe as it may be called from different threads. This includes callbacks like listeners and activators as well as services. Java EE generally expects only a single thread to be running within an application (e.g. ThreadContextClassLoader) and apps are expected not to create threads. So I expect the caution raised in that presentation is about bringing code from a Java EE environment where the code did not have to worry about concurrency to OSGi where the code should be ready for concurrency.

The OSGi specifications are all designed for concurrency. You should see @ThreadSafe and @Immutable javadoc tags throughout the OSGi API. Only in very limited circumstances will you see @NotThreadSafe javadoc tags.